# TRUE and FALSE don't work within SUM()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have boolean values in a column:

```
   A
1  TRUE
2  FALSE
3  TRUE
4  TRUE
```

I realize that in Excel `=TRUE+TRUE` returns `2` and `=TRUE+FALSE` returns `1` which implies `TRUE` is equal to `1` and `FALSE` is equal to `0`. However, `SUM(A1:A4)` always returns `0` no matter whether it is array formula style... I would expect it to be `3` (the number of `TRUE` in the range).

One way to get `3` is to use `{=SUM(IF(A1:A4,1,0))}` (array formula style), which I find redundant... Could anyone think of a simpler solution than that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try prefixing the range with `--` and entering as an array. The `--` will convert the booleans into their integer equivalents:

```
=SUM(--(A1:A4))
```

Per the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sum-HP005209290.aspx) on the `SUM` function:

> If an argument is an array or reference, only numbers in that array or
>   reference are counted. Empty cells, logical values, or text in the
>   array or reference are ignored.

Comment: Thanks... do you happen to have any other solution than `--`?

Comment: @SoftTimur What are your constraints? Counting may be your best option if you don't want to sum. However if you need to use `SUM`, I think that would be the shortest solution. Otherwise, your approach of doing the comparisons with `IF` would be another way. Basically the `SUM` function won't sum booleans in a range by design, so the options get a bit more limited :)

Comment: This is an array formula, which requires to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 38):

I've had success with COUNTIFS over a range where he condition is TRUE

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D51,TRUE)
```

Comment: In my circumstance the countifs/countif, sum etc. is not working with boolean arrays at all but the -- at the start fixed it. It was working 4 days ago though, the exact same spreadsheet. Now it is returning #N/A instead. Bizarre.

Comment: Hmm...excel can do funky things. Without having the spreadsheet, I'd check your formula and perhaps make sure your references are correct. I've moved named cells and things like that in the past and got the #N/A result too.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use sum on the true/false field you could multiple the true/false condition by 1 so that it evaluates to either 0 or 1.  Then your sum function would work on the column.

Comment: Totally underrated answer, and it's the correct one. There isn't anything much more simple than multiplying by 1, and it works beautifully.

Comment: But how do you multiply the true/false values by one (you could also add zero) within the SUM formula? Or are you suggesting using a helper column?

Comment: function sumprod(A1:A10*1)

Answer (score 0):

The `=SUM(--(A1:A4))` solution is good practice because the `--` conversion of `boolean` values is also used to enable range calculations in PRODUCT and many other functions.